# Is $f^+$ a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ be a measurable function where $(X,\Sigma_x,\mu)$ is the measurable space.

Define 
$$
f^+(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if }f(x)\ge0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Is this a measurable function? if so, why?

Comment: Consider the inverse image of an open ray under the $f^+$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\{x:f(x)\ge 0\}$. Then $$f_+=f\cdot\chi_A$$ and $A$ is a measurable set. The product of measurable functions is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f^+(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{f(x)\geq 0}(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{\{x\mid f(x)\geq 0\}}(x).$$

Comment: You want to multiply that indicator function by $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f^+$ is the composition $p\circ f$ of $f$ and the continuous (hence Borel measurable) function $p:t\to t^+$.